# Twitter Bootstrap Column Positions

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have two columns which I would like to display side by side on a desktop.

I want the following column order on a desktop (Column 2 is taller than Column 1):

```
[Column 1][Column 2]
[Column 3]
```

I want the following column order on a mobile:

```
[Column 1]
[Column 2]
[Column 3]
```

Here is an example I have created: http://jsbin.com/folekajera/1/edit?html,css,output

The problem with the example, is in the desktop view there is a gap between Column 1 and Column 3.

How would this gap be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you have the gap in the desktop view is that Bootstrap's grid has 12 columns / row.  So the first two div's use up a full row's width. The third column is effectively in it's own row.  Nitin's answer has the correct way to handle the mobile layout.

Therefore, the effective html that you actually have is below.

---

Edit - After your comment, I re-thought my answer.  There is a way to do it.  I've revised the html from my first answer.  The key item is the "pull-right" class below.  For details see [Column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering/).

`<div id="second-col" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 pull-right">`

I've updated you jsbin file at http://jsbin.com/rinejayojo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Thanks for your response @photo_tom . Is it simply not possible with Twitter Bootstrap for me to have Column 1 and Column 3 stacked with Column 2 to the right?

Comment: After your comment, I rethought my answer and figured out how to do it.  I've edited my answer with my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, completely forgot about pull-right. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

When u want something to be full on mobile its class will be "col-xs-12".

This is how it should be.

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="first-col" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
      Column 1
    </div>  
    <div id="second-col" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-8">
      Column 2
    </div>
   <div style="background-color:green" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
     Column 3
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @nitin. Are you aware of a way to remove the gap by rearranging the columns? Possibly with pull/push?