# How to make responsive grid where the second element is the last on mobile like Youtube?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I want a grid on a website like this in bootstrap 3:

Desktop (% = width):

```
ELEMENT1 (50%) ELEMENT2 (50%)
ELEMENT3 (50%)
```

Mobile:

```
ELEMENT1 (100%) 
ELEMENT2 (100%)
ELEMENT3 (100%)
```

The problem is, that Element3 on Desktop is always below the total height of ELEMENT1 and ELEMENT2.

But it should always be beneath ELEMENT1!

Another more practical example, Youtube Video:

Desktop Youtube VIdeo:

```
VIDEO (70%) SUGGESTEDVIDEOS (30%)
COMMENTS3 (70%)
```

Mobile Youtube VIdeo:

```
VIDEO (100%) 
SUGGESTEDVIDEOS (100%)
COMMENTS3 (100%)
```

My current solution has the problem that if VIDEOs height is less than SUGGESTEDVIDEOS height, theres a gap between VIDEO and COMMENTS in Desktop View.

How can I have this 3 Boxes without a gap between VIDEO and COMMENTS in Desktop View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is

```
pull-right
```

See here:
[Twitter Bootstrap Column Positions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186190/twitter-bootstrap-column-positions?rq=1)